# Remove permalink from post

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I've created a new website and installed Wordpress. I've modified the "hello, world" post with my own text and when I view the website, a permalink appears at the bottom of the post.  How to remove this?

Comment: If  possible please provide screenshot, so we can help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change in title and url also.

Please check attached file.

[image]

Comment: I've reoved the "hello, world" part, but the permalink is still showing. I want to remove it completely

Comment: In which section you want to remove it completely, please provide me screenshot, and reset the permalink also.

Comment: Lets discuss over here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170992/wp-remove-permalink-chatnew